# Vue accessing Vuex store in router file

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, store

I am trying to access my store in the router file as follow, but it's not working. Giving me undefined when I console. Any advice? I am using Vue 3. Thank you in advance!

```
import store from '../store/index'


const preventRoutes = {
  beforeEach: (to, from, next) => {
    console.log(store.getters.getLoginState);
    if (store.getters.getLoginState === "true") {
      console.log("i reached if")
      next();
    } else {
      console.log("i reached else")
      next("/");
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Do you import store in this file?

Comment: Yes. I did. Also tried $store.xxxx.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. `store` should be imported, that's the way to use it outside components. If it's not initialized at the time when beforeEach runs, that's the problem on your side. This can be the case if router and store modules have circular dependency

Comment: Thank Estus. I promise, store is imported. I edited the above code to clatify. No error to share. It is just nt working properly, and when I console logged I understood that it's undefined. Plus, anything in the store is undefined. So I am sure that store is not being read properly. Highly appreciate your support!

Answer (score 1):

maybe is because the before route load before the imports
try to import it directly from the before route:

```
router.beforeEach(function (...) {
      const store = require('./store')
      store.blah...
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar situation.
import store from "../store"; to router

then I can use store's API (commit etc ) inside router.beforeEach